# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: java, spring

I have the following property in my ApplicationContext.xml. It should load the file from the classpath datasource.properties:
`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:datasource.properties" />`
When I run the server , I had this error :
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbc.driverClassName' in value "${jdbc.driverClassName}"`.
I changed the file's name to an another name which didn't exist in the classpatch and I had the same error, I think that the `context:property-placeholder` didn't work.
I'm using spring 4.3.8 and this is my context:property-placeholder file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"       
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"
  >
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:datasource.properties" /> 

  <bean id="dataSourceMySql"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
```

Comment: check the encoding of your property file

Comment: Does your datasource.properties contain "jdbc.driverClassName" and is in resources folder of Project ?